# JQuery - Add div to parent div

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following:

```
<div id="parentCalculation">
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" id="calculate" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
</div>

Calculate below. Click on "Add to make another calculation

<div id="CalculateDiv">
<div class="calculation form-group well well-lg col-md-4">
  <label for="cost">Enter Amount</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00">
  <label for="type">Type</label>
  <input type="text" id="type" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. transfers">
  <label for="comments">Comments</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="cost-comments" placeholder="Enter comments"></textarea>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is append the parent div `CalculateDiv` with `calculation` so that there is duplicate values.

I am using the following JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
                  {

                    $("#calculate").click(function()
                    {
                        var x = $('.CalculateDiv');
                        alert(x);
                        $("#parentCalculation").append(x); 


                    });

                  });
```

The problem is that it does not add to the parent div and I can't seem to figure out why.

See example:[Here](http://www.bootply.com/Ma8nUp01HB#)

Comment: You're not creating a new element, you are simply moving it. Use `.clone()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to duplicate the element then you will have to clone `x` else you will be just relocating the element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#calculate").click(function () {
        var x = $('#CalculateDiv').clone(); //id-selector to be used also clone it
        x.removeAttr('id'); //since id of an element must be unique remove the id from clone
        $("#parentCalculation").append(x);
        //or x.appendTo('#parentCalculation');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gagLmf9v/)

---

I think you could just duplicate the `calculation` div

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#calculate").click(function () {
        var x = $('#CalculateDiv .calculation').first().clone();
        $("#CalculateDiv").append(x);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gagLmf9v/3/)

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked! The only problem is that as they are input boxes, how do I get values for each of the input for all of the added form components? I tried `$("#CalculateDiv").each(..)` but had no succsess??

Answer (score 5):

Your selector searches for a **class**, while you have html with the id:

`$('.CalculateDiv');` should be `$('#CalculateDiv');`

Comment: If I'm understanding him correctly I think he's got the class part right but the name wrong, think he wants $('.calculation')

Answer (score 0):

The jquery code is trying to find an element with "class name" as CalculateDiv. However in your html structure there is no element with class="CalculateDiv". There's one with id="CalculateDiv". Just change `$('.CalculateDiv')` to `$('#CalculateDiv')`

Also append like this

```
$("#parentCalculation").append($(x[0]).html());
```

When you just append dom object it won't make anything happen. Above code selects html content of that div and then appends it to parentCalculation div

This is how your final code should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#calculate").click(function(){
        var x = $('#CalculateDiv');
        $("#parentCalculation").append($(x[0]).html()); 
    });

});
```